# Maven plugins compilation error in fresco play handson

Tags: maven-plugin

1. Maven Plugins - 2
   Note: Maven project structure is already defined and so proceed with the following steps and do not make any changes to the pre-existing structure of PrimeSum.java and do not modify PrimeSumTest.java

- Configure your pom.xml file to include maven compiler and execution plugin and also add dependencies to generate junit test reports.
- Create a java application to calculate the sum of prime
  numbers. Also, print the sum as zero if the variable maxNum is less than or equal to zero.

I'm getting compilation error after executing pom.xml file .there is PrimeSum.java and PrimeSumTest.java file in the maven structure.